# How to write to separate columns in csv

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, visual-studio-2012

I have a html table which I am trying to write to a csv file. I have the rows seperated by a \n in my array and when I print it to the csv file everything works except one problem I'm having. I want each comma value to be printed in the next column. Unfortunately it is not doing that. My current code writes all the values from each row in the html table to the correct rows in the csv.

```
try
        {
            string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\spreadsheet.csv", true);

            foreach (var i in valueArray)
            {
                if (i.ToString() == "\n")
                {
                    sw.Write("\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    {
                        sw.Write(i.ToString());
                        sw.Write("\t");//my failed attempt
                    }
                }
            }
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();

            saveOK = true;
        }
```

values in the array would look like : "first,second,third,fourth,fith,last,\n, first, ....,last,\n,"

in the csv it shows up as :

```
              column 1                            column 2
row1 :firstsecondthirdfourthfithlast
row2 :firstsecond.......        last
```

Comment: Try writing a `,` rather than a `\t`.

Comment: You need a delimiter as @nick_w suggested

Comment: thanks. I read in a lot of places to do that, but when I tried it earlier or before, it didn't seem to work. I probably messed it up somewhere. Thank you for the help

Comment: What is the type of `valueArray`?

Comment: it was string[]. I have it working now. I didn't know csv will do the tabbing for you if you have a ","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var i in valueArray)
{
   if (i.ToString() == "\n")
   {
      sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
   }
   else
   {
      sw.Write(i.ToString() + ",");
   }
}
```