# Unable to create different columns in CSV

Tags: c#, csv

I try to create a csv file in c#. First I wrote a little piece of code to test. I saw on [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283810/how-to-write-to-separate-columns-in-csv) that the "," character is use to create different columns but it doesn't work for me.

I searched on different topic but all answer are something like `String.Format("{0},{1}", first, second);`

My code :

```
String first = "Test name";
String second = "Value";
String newLine = String.Format("{0},{1}", first, second);
csv.AppendLine(newLine);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    first = "Test_" + i;
    second = i.ToString();
    newLine = String.Format("{0},{1}", first, second);
    csv.AppendLine(newLine);
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, csv.ToString());
```

This create rightly the lines but all in column 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `csv` to be a `StringBuilder`, this should create the file

```
Test name,Value
Test_0,0
Test_1,1
Test_2,2
```

which is a valid CSV file with two columns and three rows (and headers).

Are you by any chance using a non-English locale (specifically, one that uses the comma as a decimal separator) and trying to load the CSV in Excel? In that case Excel assumes `;` as the field separator instead of `,`. You can split the data with custom settings if needed (I believe the feature is called “Text to fields”, or “Text to columns” on the Data tab in the ribbon).

Comment: You right, I have a non-English Excel. I tried with `;` and it works. But my application will run on different computer, English and  non-English. How can I be sure that user use English version ? (I don't know what is a ribbon)

Comment: I found that : `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator` it works good, I hope it will works for English version. Thank you for help

Comment: `([cultureinfo]::new('en-us')).TextInfo.ListSeparator` in PowerShell returns `,`, so should be fine. However, CSV files have no means of attaching the culture to them, so it's not nice to have them change their format depending on regional settings. I tend to take the stance that interchange formats should always be identical. In your case things would now work fine on each computer, when the application and Excel run there, but *interchange* of those files is hampered.

Comment: @A.Pissicat: There's also another option: http://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files/686415#686415

Comment: I now use both `String separator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;` and `csv.AppendLine("sep=" + separator);` to be sure. It works everywhere now, thanks to you.